# Edubuntu Computer Lab

Tags: networking, server, wine, samba, edubuntu

I'm converting my lab at school from Windows 7 to Edubuntu.

There are 24 PCs and one teacher's computer wich will also run Edubuntu.

There will be about 200 students using the lab.

There is a Windows server, but this could be converted to Ubuntu. It's only used as a login and file server.

Currently the plan is, and I'm part way there -

- Setup one PC with Edubuntu
- Install Centrify Express to allow login to domain
- Shortcut on Desktop to map a student's drive on server in Nautilus
- Wine installed to allow running of Windows apps
- Windows apps installed - paint.net,sketchup, pivot animator, etc...
- Desktop and Launcher configured under an account, copied to /etc/skel
- Build cloned to other PCs, joined to domain using Centrify

I'm just looking for feedback, advice or opinions on this setup or alternatives.

Would it be better to ditch the Windows Server asnd run 100% Linux?

What's the best way to manage multiuser accounts for apps installed with Wine?

Any tips for mapping of network shares? Each user will have a home share and a class share. Maybe this would be a lot easier in a full Linux env?

Any feedback would be great, I've been working on this for a few days now and I'm making headway with it but it's a lot slower than I thought it would be and simple things (apps in Wine, even Minecraft install) have been taking longer than they should.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update on my question

I ended up ditching Windows server and going with a full Linux job - Ubuntu server and Edubuntu clients. Ultimately I feel this was the best decision but far from perfect.

I have DHCP and DNS being provided by the server.

A great feature of this setup is the ability to cache apt requests on the server so when an update occurs then only one PC updates over the WAN via the local server. These updates are then cached on the local server and every other PC uses this cache of updates.

This took some time to setup and I ran down a few dead ends before finding Apt Cacher NG. Here is a good tutorial for setting it up - http://www.tecmint.com/apt-cache-server-in-ubuntu/

Now, for the really fun bit! - Trying to create a client-server login similar to Windows Active Directory. This took a very long time to resolve but now works pretty well, I still have a lot of work to do on it. What I'm using is OpenLDAP server. Here's a good tutorial for the server - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps, but don't use the companion one for Ubuntu 14.04 client, use this - http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=ldap&f=2

This was not an easy task but by using the log files I was able to iron out any issues and get it working.

Windows software is using Wine. There have been a few compromises here. Scratch won't install on Ubuntu 64. But Pivot, Photoshop and NWEA Test Taker all work now.

This is very much a work in progress.